# Difference in en / inspirit?

Tags: meaning, difference, word-difference, word-meaning

In a synonym dictionary, I came across the word "inspirit", which is said to mean "enliven".
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inspirit

However, then I stumbled across the word "enspirit".

I want to ask is this a difference between British and American English, or are there slight, subtle differences in the meanings to these two words?

Comment: [*enspirit* was never common, and both words are very rare these days.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inspirit%2Censpirit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinspirit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Censpirit%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: What @stangdon said. I find it ironic that the link in the question proudly identifies itself as *Oxford **living** Dictionaries*. To my mind, both ***inspirit*** and ***enspirit*** are deader than dodos, so it's a bit academic to speculate on possible differences in meaning (which I doubt ever existed anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I had to look up "inspirit". I didn't remember the word at all. I think it's very rare. "enspirit" was not in thefreedictionary.com.

Today we generally say "inspire" rather than "inspirit". I think the meaning is basically the same.